# How to count post based on taxonomy term in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

I have 2 custom post type which is

**a)** support
**b)** item

and custom taxonomy called **item_category**

I have set this **taxonomy** to **those 2 custom post**.

Now, I  want to count the post from **support** custom post based on **added** taxonomy term.

**For example:**

Taxonomy **item_category** has 3 **terms** : 1) blog 2) lms 3) event

I have added this **term** blog to **support** custom post.

Now, I want to get number of post from **only** support post type **under** blog **term**

**To do that I am using**

```
$item_categories = get_terms(array(
    'taxonomy'   => 'item_category',
    'hide_empty' => false,
));

echo "<ul class='card-content'>";
foreach ($item_categories as $item_category) {

    echo '<pre>';
        print_r($item_category);
    echo '</pre>';

    $item_category_id   = $item_category->term_id;
    $item_category_name = $item_category->name;
    $item_category_slug = $item_category->slug;
    $item_category_count = $item_category->count;

    echo "<li><a href=".site_url("/support/?item_category={$item_category_slug}").">";
        echo "<span class='lnr lnr-chevron-right'></span>{$item_category_name}";
        echo "<span class='item-count'>{$item_category_count}</span>";
    echo "</a></li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
```

But its counting from **both** **support** and **item** custom post. I want **only from support post**.

Currently, the output is like that with count value but the count is wrong according to my need.

[image]

is it possible?

Comment: i am not sure it is possible or not but i think this might be helpful : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/57444/get-terms-by-custom-post-type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get posts related to taxonomy with a tax query:

```
$posts_array = get_posts(
    array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'post_type' => 'support',
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'item_category',
                'field'    => 'term_id',
                'terms'    => $item_category_id,
            )
        )
    )
);

echo count($posts_array);
```

Comment: please check my updated question. I need to output like that.

Comment: It will be showing all terms but count only supports custom post.

Comment: @creativeartbd you will be able to get post count related to these terms using the above tax query. Use `count($posts_array)` get the number of posts.

Comment: @creativeartbd it will only get you the count for the `support` post type.

Comment: Well, does your answer will show all terms as well as the terms count?

Comment: @creativeartbd No, You need to use there inside you for loop and use `$item_category->term_id` to get the posts counts.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200997/discussion-between-jainil-and-creativeartbd).